# What are the proper terms for the way you say vs write something?

Tags: terminology, pronunciation-vs-spelling

We all know if something is three-dimensional you would write 3D. If someone says it aloud, you would hear "three dee". What are  the right terms for one vs the other?

**EDIT**

To further clarify, I am using a service which automatically creates transcripts based on an audio file. It breaks down the whole thing into duplicate copies. Something shown as "PP12" in one grouping, is shown as "PP", "one", "two" in another. In other cases it will have "3D" in one and "three", "D" in the other. It made me wonder if there is some official terminology between how you show a written word vs how you would say it aloud.

I basically wanted to know if there were more official words than "read as" vs "spoken as".

Comment: But we do write "3D"  (https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/3d).  English is a descriptive language.  We can and do write things exactly how we say them.  The only reasons writing is ever different are we have more time to think and hone what we're going to say and we are at times afraid that the lack of visual and oral cues might cause what we've written to be misunderstood, thus rewording it in a way that we hope is less likely to be.

Comment: I don't know.  Maybe what you're trying to get at is "formal" and "informal," but that applies to speech as well as writing, just some people may find that they are called upon to communicate formally in writing than they are called upon to communicate formally in speech.

Comment: Hi Dave. The first is "written" the second is "spoken" ?

Comment: 'vs' is short for 'versus', so that's how you say it.

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback. My first question on here. I'll go clarify! Hopefully I can get rid of being -1 ;)